# C# Printing with dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a problem with the algorithm Fisher in c#.

I have a class system of SystemDecyzyjny. In it I have a dictionary.

```
public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>> posortowane = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>();
```

Data in dictionary:
[image]

How to display with posortowane data in Form1.cs in this form:
2 4 1 3
. . . .
. . . .

How to refer to the dictionary and display data from it attributes?

Comment: What is the question? Are you wondering how to print the contents of a dictionary?

Comment: Are you looking to just get the keys?  `posortowane.Keys` would give you that enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the value of the key 0, then you just write this:

```
posortowane[0]
```

This returns a `Dictionary<int, double>`.

Now you can read the value with key 0 of the latter dictionary as:

```
posortowane[0][0]
```

The value with the key 1 as:

```
posortowane[0][1]
```

and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to print out all keys of the inner dictionary. This can be done in the following way:

```
foreach (var outerKey in posortowane.Keys)
{
    foreach (var inner in posortowane[outerKey])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inner.Key);
    }
}
```

If you want to print out the **both** the keys and values of the inner dictionary you could do:

```
foreach (var outerKey in posortowane.Keys)
{
    foreach (var inner in posortowane[outerKey])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{inner.Key}:{inner.Value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, dictionary: <int,<int,double>> 

I wants a second int

Comment: What do you mean? The first example prints out the second (inner key) int.